# How do I export Server Group configurations?

Tags: azure-data-studio

How can I export to file my Server Group configurations in Azure Data Studio?

I've created a Workspace file in my application solution that contains useful queries for troubleshooting, etc. I'd like to also include connection configurations for servers relevant to the solution so that any developer can use the Workspace queries quickly without having to ask which servers to run them on.

Answer (score 15):

All connections and groups are located in the `settings.json` file located at:

```
%AppData%\azuredatastudio\User\
```

For me specifically the path looked like this:

```
C:\Users\MyLogin123\AppData\Roaming\azuredatastudio\User
```

Answer (score 12):

You can copy your Server Group configurations from User Settings. You will find them under `datasource.connectionGroups` and connection details under `datasource.connections` (if you have different ones, check with the group id). Any user can copy and paste them into his user settings except the password. Everyone needs to add that individually after the fact. I would suggest creating a JSON file with those settings and adding the steps to a `readme.md` file. [image]